# What is this linker error about (SDL2 using vscode on windows)?

Tags: c++, linker-errors

Trying to build my c++ project using SDL2, but it gives me this error, even though I think I am linking everything correctly:

```
C:\Users\spr\AppData\Local\Temp\ccW5VQkj.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xbe): undefined reference to ` `RenderWindow::RenderWindow(char const*, int, int)'
C:\Users\spr\AppData\Local\Temp\ccW5VQkj.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xf9): undefined reference to ` `RenderWindow::cleanUp()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am building like this:

```
all:
    g++ -Isrc/include -Lsrc/lib -o build/main src/main.cpp -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image
```

here is the code for main.cpp:

```cpp
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "custom/RenderWindow.hpp"

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) > 0)
        std::cout << "HEY.. SDL_Init HAS FAILED. SDL_ERROR: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;

    if (!(IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG)))
        std::cout << "IMG_init has failed. Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;

    RenderWindow window("GAME v1.0", 1280, 720);

    bool gameRunning = true;

    SDL_Event event;

    while (gameRunning)
    {
        // Get our controls and events
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
                gameRunning = false;
        }
    }

    window.cleanUp();
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

RenderWindow.hpp:

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>

class RenderWindow 
{
public:
    RenderWindow(const char* p_title, int p_w, int p_h);
    void cleanUp();
private:
    SDL_Window* window;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer;
};
```

and renderwindow.cpp

```cpp
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "custom/RenderWindow.hpp"

RenderWindow::RenderWindow(const char* p_title, int p_w, int p_h)
    :window(NULL), renderer(NULL)
{
    window = SDL_CreateWindow(p_title, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, p_w, p_h, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Window failed to init. Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    }

    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
}

void RenderWindow::cleanUp()
{
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
}
```

I am trying to follow codergophers 10 part tutorial on c++ (but I am using vscode instead of sublime). Is there something I need to do differently in order to link? I am new to c++ programming.

Comment: You need to add `renderwindow.cpp` to the list of files you are compiling.  The command line above only has `src/main.cpp`.

Comment: @RichardCritten Thank you, I changed it to 

g++ -Isrc/include -Lsrc/lib -o build/main src/*.cpp -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Built it without including `renderwindow.cpp` so I changed the way I built it to `g++ -Isrc/include -Lsrc/lib -o build/main src/*.cpp -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image` so it includes all `.cpp` files.